# How to iter over pandas time_stamp column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have a DataFrame which has a time_stamp column that I created with `pd.to_datetime` function.

```
date_start             | column2 |  column3  | column...
2018-09-22 12:30:00          x         x        x
```

I am not able to match the time stamp when I try to iter over this column.

for example when I get nothing when I try:

```
for i in df['date_start']: 
    if i == user_entry: 
        print('something')
```

I never get the correct out put even when there is definitely a matching value in the user's entry.

can any one help ?

Comment: What does `user_entry` look like? If it's coming from `input` (or `raw_input`, depending on which version of Python you're using), it's `str`, not of a "datetime" nature

Comment: Impossible to answer without a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what `user_entry` represents, but I'm fairly sure it's something like this... Take a look at the following:

Create your Series of a datetime nature:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s = pd.Series(['01/01/2018', '01/02/2018', '12/25/2018'])
>>> s = pd.to_datetime(s)
>>> s
0   2018-01-01
1   2018-01-02
2   2018-12-25
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Get user entry using `input`:

```
>>> user_entry = input()
01/02/2018
>>> type(user_entry)
<class 'str'>
```

Now, convert that `user_entry` to a datetime object:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> user_entry = datetime.datetime.strptime(user_entry, '%m/%d/%Y')
>>> user_entry
datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 2, 0, 0)
```

Proceed with your iteration:

```
>>> for dt in s:
...     if dt == user_entry:
...             print('Match')
... 
Match
```

Comment: I think you got lucky this time -- next time, please make sure to provide more information, so that others can reproduce your error. It was sort of lucky I inferred your problem here, but with more complex problems it's really helpful to provide more of a background. Cheers and welcome to the site.

Comment: Also, feel free to mark this answer as accepted so others know it's been resolved (checkmark next to the voting buttons on the left of this answer)

Comment: I'll be sure to do just that next time mate. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas vectorised methods. There's no need to introduce the `datetime` module from the standard library, since `pd.to_datetime` works with scalars and a variety of human-readable formats:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['01/01/2018 12:30:00', '01/02/2018 15:20:12', '12/25/2018 10:45:15'])
s = pd.to_datetime(s)

user_entry = input()  # input '2018-01-01 12:30:00'

if (s == pd.to_datetime(user_entry)).any():
    print('Match found!')

# 2018-01-01 12:30:00
# Match found!
```